# Minimizing sequence that has certain property

Tags: real-analysis

I saw this kind of minimizing sequence on a paper. I don't see how it's possible.

Let's say I have a normed vector space $V$. $W$ is a subset of $V$. And I have a functional $f$ on $W$. Can I pick a minimizing sequence $\{u_i\}$ such that

1. $\lim f(u_i)=\inf_W f(u)$
2. $f(u_i)\leq f(u)+{1\over i} ||u_i-u||$ for any $u\in W$.

I don't see why this can always be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $V=W=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=2x$ in $W$. Given any sequence $\left\{u_i\right\}$ and $i\geq 2$, if we let $u=u_i/2\in W$, then $$f(u_i)=2u_i=2(u_i/2)+|2u_i-2(u_i/2)|=f(u)+|f(u_i)-f(u)|>f(u)+(1/i)|f(u_i)-f(u)|.$$

Usually, properties such as 2. are obtained if you have some conditions of $f$ and $W$, such as closedness/boundedness of $W$, reflexivity of $V$, convexity of $f$, $\inf f(W)>-\infty$, etc...